# create singleton objects which requires parameters to build and access them anywhere

Tags: rust

I have lot of Singleton objects created inside main and shared across different parts of the code using `Arc`, which feels like a very bad design. Can somebody suggest a better way of designing the below code

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::mpsc;

pub struct A {
    rx: mpsc::Receiver::<i32>,
    x_obj: Arc<X>,
    y_obj: Arc<Y>,
    // ... contains many more Arc fields
}

impl A {
    pub fn new(rx: mpsc::Receiver::<i32>, x_obj: Arc<X>, y_obj: Arc<Y> /* , ... contains many more Arc parameters */) -> A {
        A {
            rx,
            x_obj,
            y_obj,
            // ... contains many more Arc fields initializations
        }
    }
    
    pub fn a_func(&self) {
        // uses self.x_obj syntax currently
        // instead can we directly access the x_obj if it can be created globally
    }
}

pub struct B {
    rx: mpsc::Receiver::<f64>,
    y_obj: Arc<Y>,
    z_obj: Arc<Z>,
    // ... contains many more Arc fields
}

impl B {
    pub fn new(rx: mpsc::Receiver::<f64>, y_obj: Arc<Y>, z_obj: Arc<Z> /* , ... contains many more Arc parameters */) -> B {
        B {
            rx,
            y_obj,
            z_obj,
            // ... contains many more Arc fields initializations
        }
    }
    
    pub fn b_func(&self) {
        // uses self.y_obj syntax currently
        // instead can we directly access the y_obj if it can be created globally
    }
}

pub struct C {
    rx: mpsc::Receiver::<String>,
    x_obj: Arc<X>,
    z_obj: Arc<Z>,
    // ... contains many more Arc fields
}

impl C {
    pub fn new(rx: mpsc::Receiver::<String>, x_obj: Arc<X>, z_obj: Arc<Z> /* , ... contains many more Arc parameters */) -> C {
        C {
            rx,
            x_obj,
            z_obj,
            // ... contains many more Arc fields initializations
        }
    }
    
    pub fn c_func(&self) {
        // uses self.z_obj syntax currently
        // instead can we directly access the z_obj if it can be created globally
    }
}

struct X {
    
}

impl X {
    pub fn new() -> X {
        X {
            
        }
    }
}

struct Y {
    
}

impl Y {
    pub fn new() -> Y {
        Y {
            
        }
    }
}

struct Z {
    
}

impl Z {
    pub fn new() -> Z {
        Z {
            
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Arc::new(X::new());
    let y = Arc::new(Y::new());
    let z = Arc::new(Z::new());
    
    // share the above structs accross the A, B, C struct Arc instances
    // let a = Arc::new(A::new(...))
    // let b = Arc::new(B::new(...))
    // let c = Arc::new(C::new(...))
}
```

Comment: I think your question could be improved by being more specific about what you see as the "bad" part of your current design.

Comment: basically passing too many `Arc` parameters to `new` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [OnceCell](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.OnceCell.html), or [OnceLock](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.OnceLock.html) if you need thread safety, will be worth investigating for your scenario.

Pseudo-example:

Given a module :

```
    pub struct SomeSingletonStruct {
        // definition and impl omitted 
    }
    
    pub static SOME_STATIC: OnceCell<SomeSingletonStruct> = OnceCell::const_new();
    
    pub fn initialise() {
        let s = SomeSingleton::new();
        SOME_STATIC.set(s).unwrap();
    }
```

Then obviously call `initialise` somewhere in your main startup code.

And then reference the static entity in other modules thus:

```
use my_module::SOME_STATIC;

let my_ref = SOME_STATIC.get().expect("static not initialised");
```